# c++ fails to find includes

Tags: c++, libraries

Just installed build-essentinals in debian 7. 
But i noticed the includes for c++ are in /usr/include/c++/4.7... 
Does anyone why? Includes used to be in /usr/include, as far as I remember...

Everything fails now... 
i.e.

```
main.c:2:20: fatal error  iostream: No such file or directory
```

And even if i include it with -I, headers are called from headers and it won't find anything, like:

```
/usr/include/features.h:323:26: fatal error: bits/predefs.h: No such file or directory
```

So beacuse bits is NOT in /usr/include but in /usr/include/c++/4.7 compiler can't find it...

I'm using g++

```
crafter# g++ -o craft main.cpp 
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/os_defines.h:40:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/c++config.h:414,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/features.h:323:26: fatal error: bits/predefs.h: No such file or directory
```

compilation terminated.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are the `gcc` and `g++` packages installed?

Comment: @GoBusto `gcc` and `g++` are dependencies of `build-essential`, so yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stated by Stefano Sanfilipo, there was indeed a mixup with 32 and 64 bit libraries.

I solved as suggested by removing all dev packages:

```
apt-get remove --purge libc6-dev
apt-get remove --purge libc6-dev-i386
```

And then reinstalling:

```
apt-get install build-essential
```

And now it compiles perfectly.

MSalters also saw the problem though, what shold I do in this case so that both get credit?

Regards,

David

Answer (score 6):

You are using `gcc` to compile C++ code, which results in C++ system headers not being considered in the header lookup process. Use `g++` command instead.

Also, you should rename `main.c` to `main.cpp` since you are using C++ 
features.

Finally, compiling a `.cpp` file with `gcc` will clear the preprocessing and compiling phase, but fail the linking, because `libstdc++` will not be implicitly added.

Your command line should look like `g++ main.cpp -o outname`.

Comment: @DavidVillasmil >>> `Also, you should rename main.c to main.cpp`

Comment: Please check what architecture targets the `libc6-dev` you got installed. It must be `amd64`, but you might have got the `i686` version somehow. You can do that with `dpkg -l libc6-dev`.

Comment: changing main.c to main.cpp fix the problem

Answer (score 2):

Apparently a [32/64 bit mixup](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1877944). Solved by installing `libc6-dev-i386` for 32 bits builds, or by building for 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the include directlory in a `-I` argument to the compiler, something like:

```
$(CC) -I/usr/include/c++/4.7 ...
```

Comment: This is not a good solution because the overall problem still remains -- these are system includes the poster is having a problem with, they should never require a "-I" to use.